# Collection of functions from finite sets to finite sets

Tags: set-theory

When talking about "all functions from a fixed set $S$ to any finite set", do we talk about a "set", a "class", or neither (something else perhaps)?
$$C = \{f \colon S \to R \colon R \text{ is a finite set}\}$$

My take is that:

- They do not form a set, since the collection already includes all finite sets, which does not form a set.
- However, it is alright to talk about them as a *class*, and nobody (at least in ZFC) will complain about the terminology.

Is this reasonning correct?

Comment: You may as well take $R$ to be a set of the form $\{1, ..., n\}$ for some positive integer $n$.

Comment: In your first bullet, you should say it includes all the ordered pairs.  The set $\{1\}$ is not a function, but it is a finite set.  That does not change the effect.  It shows that the collection is class size.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this reasoning is correct. ZFC in particular is only able to talk about *definable* classes, which are those classes where comprehension using a first-order formula is enough to specify its elements exactly. An example of a class that isn't definable is the elementary embedding $j:V\to V$ in the presence of a Reinhardt cardinal (to be able to reason about $j$ as an object, we need to use an extension of the language of ZFC, two common ways are adding a function symbol $j$ and using second-order logic.)

In particular, $C$ is a definable class because the notions "$x$ is finite", "$f$ is a function", and "$x$ is the range of the function $f$" are all definable by first-order formulae. (A standard reference for their defining formulae is a set theory textbook like Jech's *Set Theory*.)